# Does the .NET JIT compiler only get one chance to load an assembly?

Tags: .net, jit

When the JIT compiler needs a type definition for a type in an assembly that is not yet loaded, but the loader fails to load that assembly (eg. FileNotFoundException, or UnauthorizedAccessException), JIT-compilation of the method using that type obviously fails.

If the method is subsequently called again in the same AppDomain, is the JIT-compiler/loader supposed to try to load the assembly again?

Experimentation seems to suggest that the JIT compiler only gets one shot at having an assembly loaded, every subsequent call to the same method yields the same exception, even if the original condition that led to that exception was resolved (ie. the file now exists, or the file permissions were corrected).

Is there any detailed internals documentation on how the JIT compiler or loader deals with this type of assembly load failure?

Comment: One shot. Once an assembly load fails it will fail consistently afterwards, even if it would not have to fail.  Standard CLR rule.  Does not apply to loads without a context (LoadFile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any documentation regarding how Microsoft's commercial CLR behaves in this scenario. I suspect it is not detailed in the ECMA specification.

However, the [Shared Source Common Language Infrastructure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=4917) (SSCLI, aka Rotor) handles this situation by having the JIT-compiler emit code to throw the exception. This is quite a neat solution, allowing the exception to be raised when the managed-code is executed, rather than the un-managed VM having to report an error.

The call-site is then back-patched to call the emitted code, so the JIT will not attempt to load the assembly again, at least not from that call-site.

Given Rotor was based on the commercial CLR, it seems likely that it behaves in a similar manner, but perhaps someone who worked on it can verify?